# How to read a csv file with Pandas with more delimiters in the rows that in the header?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I want to read a csv file using read_csv function from Pandas, the file has more delimiters in the rows that in the header. Pandas thinks the first columns are multi-index. The 'NAME' column can have an arbitrary number of delimiters and the affected column could be any one (we do not know which one is affected), even more than one.

I have tried to tune the key-word arguments of read_csv without success. I am using Python 3.7.0 and Pandas 0.25.0. However, Excel can read the file correctly.

```py
import pandas

with open('test.csv', mode='w') as csv_file:
    csv_file.write('A,NAME,B\n')
    csv_file.write('a, Peter, Parker, b\n')

df = pandas.read_csv('test.csv', header=0, delimiter=',')
print(df)
```

Expected output:

```
   A            NAME   B
0  a   Peter, Parker   b
```

Actual output:

```
    A     NAME   B
a   Peter   Parker   b
```

Other example:

```py
import pandas

with open('test.csv', mode='w') as csv_file:
    csv_file.write('A,NAME,B,PLACE\n')
    csv_file.write('a, Peter, Parker, b, Queens, New York City\n')

df = pandas.read_csv('test.csv', header=0, delimiter=',')
print(df)
```

Expected output:

```
   A            NAME   B                 PLACE
0  a   Peter, Parker   b Queens, New York City
```

Actual output:

```
                A NAME        B           PLACE
a  Peter   Parker    b   Queens   New York City
```

Comment: Does every `NAME` has this format?

Comment: No. There can exists an arbitrary number of delimiters in each row, but the same along all rows.

Comment: Okay, there are a number of ways to tackle this but it does not make sense to structure the data like that. Who makes a csv files like that? If you want a proper  solution, I suggest you come up with more data that covers all possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't something like

```
df = pandas.read_csv('test.csv', header=0, delimiter=',')
df = df.reset_index()
df["NAME"] = df["A"] + ", " + df["NAME"]
df["A"] = df["Unnamed: 0"]
df = df.drop("Unnamed: 0", axis=1)
```

possible ? It is not completely answering this question but could do the trick for your df.

EDIT : Another possibility, if the file is also available in .xls/.xlsx format, `pd.read_excel("name.xls")` should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

A workaround:

```
with open('test.csv', mode='w') as csv_file:  
    csv_file.write('A,NAME,B\n')  
    csv_file.write('a, Peter, Parker, b\n')  
    csv_file.write('aa, John, Lee, Mary, bb\n')            

df=pd.DataFrame(columns=["A","NAMES","B"])                                                                           

with open("test.csv") as ff:  
   for line in ff:  
       A,N= line.split(",",maxsplit=1)  
       N,B= N.rsplit(",",maxsplit=1)  
       df.loc[len(df.index)]= [A.strip(),N.strip(),B.strip()] 

df.drop(0,axis="index")

    A            NAMES   B
1   a    Peter, Parker   b
2  aa  John, Lee, Mary  bb
```

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify that the affect column could be anyone. Even more than one.

Comment: @aciba What are the rules?  You must specify the part numbers in columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Read first line as a list using ',' as delimiter
with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
  header = f.readline().replace('\n', '').split(',')
# Read file skipping first line (header) using two character delimiter ', '
df = pandas.read_csv('test.csv', skiprows = 1, header = None, delimiter=', ', engine = 'python')
header = header + ["missing-column"] # In your example file header has only 3 columns but data has 4
# Assign header list as dataframe columns names
df.columns = header
print(df)
```

Comment: "# In your example file header has only 3 columns but data has 4" is exactly the problem. Pandas would like Pandas to be smart enough to understand "Peter, Parker" as a column.

Answer (score 0):

#### Initial thoughts

I agree with some of the commenters that the issue lies in the format that the file was first saved in. It is not proper CSV format to be saving strings in the file in this way. They should be surrounded by double quotes. It would seem to me that the best way to fix this is to save it down correctly in the first place.

Of course that might not be possible given your circumstances so let's see what we can do.

#### Your example

Here is the .csv file representation that I think your first example would have:

```
A,NAME,B
a,Peter, Parker,b
```

I too see the same behavior when loading into pandas:

```
        A     NAME  B
a   Peter   Parker  b
```

*(Also, Excel does not load it correctly for me either which is strange, but beside the point.)*

#### Foothold into a solution

I see two key pieces of information that might help us here:

1. The number of expected columns provided to us by the number of items in the header. This tells us the total number of items that should be in each row of the output.
2. We know that the first header must go with the data in the first part of each row. Be that the only index item in your first example, or the first of the multi-index in your second example, etc.

I don't see where those two assumptions get us on their own though. This is because we know how many columns we have and how many there should be, but we don't know which ones should be collapsed where. I don't think that can be knowable in a comprehensive generalized case.

#### Unless...

This assumption is the shakiest, but we *might* be able to assume that there will be a leading whitespace on substrings that were incorrectly moved to the next column label. This is the case in both of the examples you provided and it could save our skin. If that assumption does hold, here is what you could do:

## Solution if leading whitespace can be assumed

We are going to rebuild the columns one by one. We will put the first column in the first header, then look to see if the next one has a leading whitespace. If it does, we can append to the current one and then check the next one. This should work an arbitrary number of broken columns as long as they all have a leading whitespace.

Code:

```
# Import IO so we can import the string directly. This makes it much more clear
# the data that we are working with without us having to load a file that is
# unseen in the code
import io

raw_csv_string = """A,NAME,B,PLACE
a,Peter, Parker,b,Queens, New York City"""

# A buffer that pandas can read from as if it was a file
string_buffer = io.StringIO(raw_csv_string)

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(string_buffer)


def re_collapse_broken_comma_columns(df:pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    # Store the columns that we should expect to see
    true_headers = df.columns
    
    # Pull the data that got incorrectly placed in the index out of the index
    flattened_index = df.reset_index()
    
    # index helper that will keep track of where we are as we move through the
    # names of the true headers
    true_header_i = 0
    # Helper boolean for adding new columns
    direct_add = True
    
    # Empty dataframe that our cleaned data will go in
    output = pd.DataFrame()
    
    for i, column in enumerate(flattened_index.columns):
        # Store the data in this particular column
        data = flattened_index[column]
    
        # Check to make sure we still have true headers to put data into
        if true_header_i < len(true_headers):
            # Store the name for conveinience
            current_true_column = true_headers[true_header_i]
        else:
            raise RuntimeError(
                "We ran out of true headers. Cannot be fixed with this method."
                + " There is a comma cleaved column in the data that needs to be"
                + " recombined which didn't fit the criteria for combination."
            )
    
        # If direct_add we are safe to place a column directly in a true_header
        # with no priors
        if direct_add:
            output[current_true_column] = data
        # Else we must place in the previous true_header
        else:
            # Insert the column we lost
            output[current_true_column] = output[current_true_column] + "," + data
    
        # Data in the next column if there is one
        next = None
        if i + 1 < len(flattened_index.columns):
            next = flattened_index[flattened_index.columns[i + 1]]
    
        # If there is no next, we are done here
        if next is None:
            break
    
        #
        whitespace_test = next.str.contains("\A\s", na=False)
    
        if whitespace_test.iloc[0] & (len(whitespace_test.unique() == 1)):
            direct_add = False
        else:
            direct_add = True
            true_header_i += 1
    
    # Final validation
    if len(true_headers) != len(output.columns):
        raise RuntimeError(
            "Recombination occurred too often. We have fewer columns in the"
            + " output than were expected."
        )

    return output

output = re_collapse_broken_comma_columns(df)
```

The returned output data frame has the correct shape in both of the examples you provided as well as some other test cases that I ran. Again, it breaks if the assumption cannot hold, but I think this is the best we can do.